# how to place the radial menu center of all devices in android programing

Tags: android, menu

I have a radial menu. I want to align it center off all screens horizontally and vertically. The code used to place the radial menu is:

```
pieMenu.setCenterLocation(500,500)
```

but it places the menu using pixel units I think.

```
menuExpandItem  = new RadialMenuItem(getString(R.string.about),
            getString(R.string.about));
    menuExpandItem .setDisplayIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    menuExpandItem 
            .setOnMenuItemPressed(new RadialMenuItem.RadialMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void execute() {
                    // Can edit based on preference. Also can add animations
                    // here.
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,
                            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(mFragmentContainer.getId(),
                                    new RadialMenuAboutFragment()).commit();

                }
            });

  //  pieMenu.setDismissOnOutsideClick(true, menuLayout);
    pieMenu.setAnimationSpeed(0L);
    pieMenu.setSourceLocation(3,200);
    pieMenu.setIconSize(15, 30);
    pieMenu.setTextSize(13);
    pieMenu.setInnerRingRadius(45,90);
    pieMenu.setCenterLocation(550,1500);
    pieMenu.setOutlineColor(Color.BLACK, 225);
    pieMenu.setInnerRingColor(0xfbce25, 180);
    pieMenu.setOuterRingColor(0x0099CC, 180);
    //pieMenu.setHeader("Test Menu", 20);
    pieMenu.setCenterCircle(menuCloseItem);

    pieMenu.addMenuEntry(new ArrayList<RadialMenuItem>() {
        {
            add(menuItem);
            add(menuExpandItem);
            add(menuHome);
        }
    });
```

Comment: why are you using a code? do it in xml

Comment: could you please provide us some code ?

Comment: @DegenSharew it should be code in the java classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the screen display dimensions in pixel grammatically using `getSize` as follows

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

If you're not in an Activity you can get the default Display via WINDOW_SERVICE:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)    context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Now you can calculate the center and use it in your code.

```
pieMenu.setCenterLocation(width/2,height/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

without seeing more code, i would do a :

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
pieMenu.setCenterLocation(width/2,height/2);
```

But it would be really useful if you could provide us with more information on what, and from where, you are building it (fragment? dialog? activity? view?).